# Getting error "Cannot call 'plot' with 'series'=series[bool]"

Tags: pine-script

I want to plot a line above only long entries on a strategy, not short entries.

But, when I try to code it I get error :

`"Cannot call 'plot' with 'series'=series[bool]. The argument should be of type: series[float]."`

My code is as follows:

```
Entry = strategy.position_avg_price
LongPosition = (strategy.position_size > 0)
LongTargetLine   = LongPosition and (Entry + 0.002)

plot (LongTargetLine,  "Long Target", color.blue, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a few mixed up variables here, but its a simple fix as you were very close! The compile error was due to the plot series needing to be a number and we mixed a bool with a float in the LongTargetLine variable. See the re-organization below:

```
Entry = strategy.position_avg_price
LongPosition = strategy.position_size > 0
LongTargetLine = Entry + 0.002

plot (LongPosition ? LongTargetLine : na,  "Long Target", color.blue, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

We can set a condition longPosition to check that we are in a position before referencing the plot value in a ternary operator. This makes the plot na if we are not long.